# Selecting column on the basis of multiple other column values

Tags: sql, postgresql

My table is as below -

```
id   p_id     Date        Tag
---------------------------------
1    1     11/02/2019     tag_1
2    1     12/02/2019     tag_2
3    7     20/01/2019     tag_3
4    1     13/02/2019     tag_2
5    8     25/11/2019     tag_1
6    7     26/02/2019     tag_4
```

I want to create a table from the above table which will be as below -

```
   p_id     Date_1    Date_2    Date_3
-----------------------------------------
   1     11/02/2019 12/02/2019 13/02/2019
   7     20/01/2019 26/02/2019 Null
   8     25/11/2019 Null       Null
```

This table has to be created using the logic that for rows having **tag_1, tag_3**, the date has to be fetched in Date_1 column and if the rows have tags **tag_2, tag_4**, the date has to be fetched in Date_2/Date_3 column. Here, the catch is that let's say in the above example only against P_id = 1 we had tag_2 repeated twice. So, if any tag out of **tag_2, tag_4** is getting repeated twice then the second date should be entered in Date_3 column and the first one should be entered in Date_2 column.

Any Suggestions? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with

```
select  p_id,
    max(case when rank = 1 then date end) date_1,
    max(case when rank = 2 then date end) date_2,
    max(case when rank = 3 then date end) date_3
from    (
select  t.*,rank() over (partition by t.p_id order by date) rank
from    table_name t
)t group by 1
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=677d294f2ff8b7751916e6f920cf6854)**

Comment: I tried the above logic but it seems that there is a slight problem here. I am getting ranks like 1,2,3,4...... and it is increasing by 1. Due to this, I am just getting only single row in my answer since we are fetching data against rank =1,2&3. Can you help me troubleshoot this?

Comment: #Ayush Agrawal - Please see the Fiddle Demo.

Answer (score 1):

If you want separate columns, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select p_id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then date end) as date_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then date end) as date_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then date end) as date_3
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by p_id order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by p_id;
```

However, if you want to gather the columns, I think I would recommend arrays instead of separate columns:

```
select p_id, array_agg(date order by date) as dates
from t
group by p_id;
```

You can extend this to your format as well:

```
select p_id,
       (array_agg(date order by date))[1] as date_1,
       (array_agg(date order by date))[2] as date_2,
       (array_agg(date order by date))[3] as date_3
from t
group by p_id;
```